# count of dictionary keys inside of (key, {key, value}) records

Tags: pyspark

This is part of homework question, and a simple conceptual question. I have key value records in PySpark, where the values are dictionaries of various sizes.

testRDD.collect() returns

```
["2\t{'3': 1}",
 "3\t{'2': 1}",
 "4\t{'1': 1, '2': 1}",
 "5\t{'4': 1, '2': 1, '6': 1}",
 "6\t{'2': 1, '5': 1}",
 "7\t{'2': 1, '5': 1}",
 "8\t{'2': 1, '5': 1}",
 "9\t{'2': 1, '5': 1}",
 "10\t{'5': 1}",
 "11\t{'5': 1}"]
```

I have started with

```
totalCount = dataRDD.map(lambda x: x.split("\t")) \
```

and have ~3 more lines of code to complete in order to count the number of distinct keys in the dictionaries. A hint for the key-(key-value) format (i.e. the next line of my pyspark code) should be all that I need to get going. I have tried to take .keys() inside flatMap and flatMapValues() [with a lambda function] without success. In the case of .keys(), I am told I have a list, not a dictionary. I understand why that is but I'm at a loss on how to handle this.

Expected result, at the end of my pyspark query, will be a simple count of 6 for this testRDD.

I see from similar questions a list comprehension might be the solution, but I'm still not so familiar at using this inside of a map()? lambda function in pyspark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this problem you need to use `rdd concepts like map, flatMap, distinct` and `python lambda, eval` Here are steps: -

**Lets start with creating rdd: -**

```
my_rdd = sc.parallelize(["2\t{'3': 1}",
 "3\t{'2': 1}",
 "4\t{'1': 1, '2': 1}",
 "5\t{'4': 1, '2': 1, '6': 1}",
 "6\t{'2': 1, '5': 1}",
 "7\t{'2': 1, '5': 1}",
 "8\t{'2': 1, '5': 1}",
 "9\t{'2': 1, '5': 1}",
 "10\t{'5': 1}",
 "11\t{'5': 1}"
])
my_rdd.collect()

["2\t{'3': 1}",
 "3\t{'2': 1}",
 "4\t{'1': 1, '2': 1}",
 "5\t{'4': 1, '2': 1, '6': 1}",
 "6\t{'2': 1, '5': 1}",
 "7\t{'2': 1, '5': 1}",
 "8\t{'2': 1, '5': 1}",
 "9\t{'2': 1, '5': 1}",
 "10\t{'5': 1}",
 "11\t{'5': 1}"]
```

Then split with `\t` and `eval` dict: -

```
new_my_rdd = my_rdd.map(lambda x:eval(x.split("\t")[1]))
new_my_rdd.collect()
[{'3': 1},
 {'2': 1},
 {'1': 1, '2': 1},
 {'2': 1, '4': 1, '6': 1},
 {'2': 1, '5': 1},
 {'2': 1, '5': 1},
 {'2': 1, '5': 1},
 {'2': 1, '5': 1},
 {'5': 1},
 {'5': 1}]
```

**Now extract keys only and use `flatMap` to convert them in rows: -**

```
new_my_rdd2 = new_my_rdd.flatMap(lambda x:x.keys())
new_my_rdd2.collect()
['3',
 '2',
 '1',
 '2',
 '2',
 '4',
 '6',
 '2',
 '5',
 '2',
 '5',
 '2',
 '5',
 '2',
 '5',
 '5',
 '5']
```

**Finally, count distinct values:-**

```
new_my_rdd2.distinct().count()
6
```

Comment: Can you explain eval() in this context a bit more? How come this doesn't work without it? (I get an AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys')

Comment: @FredericBastiat after splitting with `\t` we will get `"{'3': 1}"` this as value to parse. But this is in the string so how we can get keys from it as string don't have keys. To convert this string into dictionary used eval.  Eval converts a string to python variable & structures.

Answer (score 1):

One more way of solving this problem with RDD approach.

```
>>> rdd=["2\t{'3': 1}", "3\t{'2': 1}", "4\t{'1': 1, '2': 1}", "5\t{'4': 1, '2': 1, '6': 1}", "6\t{'2': 1, '5': 1}", "7\t{'2': 1, '5': 1}", "8\t{'2': 1, '5': 1}", "9\t{'2': 1, '5': 1}", "10\t{'5': 1}", "11\t{'5': 1}"]
>>> rdd
["2\t{'3': 1}", "3\t{'2': 1}", "4\t{'1': 1, '2': 1}", "5\t{'4': 1, '2': 1, '6': 1}", "6\t{'2': 1, '5': 1}", "7\t{'2': 1, '5': 1}", "8\t{'2': 1, '5': 1}", "9\t{'2': 1, '5': 1}", "10\t{'5': 1}", "11\t{'5': 1}"]
>>> rdd_1=sc.parallelize(rdd)
>>> rdd_1.collect()
["2\t{'3': 1}", "3\t{'2': 1}", "4\t{'1': 1, '2': 1}", "5\t{'4': 1, '2': 1, '6': 1}", "6\t{'2': 1, '5': 1}", "7\t{'2': 1, '5': 1}", "8\t{'2': 1, '5': 1}", "9\t{'2': 1, '5': 1}", "10\t{'5': 1}", "11\t{'5': 1}"]
>>> rdd_2=rdd_1.flatMap(lambda x:x.split("\t")[1].split(",")).map(lambda x:x.replace("'","").replace("'",""))
>>> len(set(rdd_2.map(lambda x:x.replace('{','').replace('}','').replace(' ','').split(":")[0]).collect()))
6
```

Comment: couldn't be more beautiful